# Does ClockKit support custom text sizes in complications?

Tags: watchkit, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I'm working on a timer app for Apple Watch and would like to provide a circular complication with the remaining duration of a timer.

Here is some example code, which you can preview in Xcode 12:

```
import ClockKit
import SwiftUI

struct CircularSmallComplicationTemplate {

    let text: String

    func make() -> CLKComplicationTemplate {
        let textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: text)
        return CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText(textProvider: textProvider, fillFraction: 1.0, ringStyle: .closed)
    }
}

struct CircularSmallComplicationTemplate_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircularSmallComplicationTemplate(text: "5:00").make()
            .previewContext()
    }
}
```

ClockKit applies the default text size, which causes text with more than three characters to truncate:

[image: Truncated text in complication]

I wonder if it is possible to shrink the text to fit inside the circle? I know that I could also use SwiftUI to draw the content, but this is only supported for the `Graphic` complication slots.